# Is there a way to retrieve the event's delegate

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I am wondering whether I can retrieve an event's delegate list of a class object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have implemented the event yourself, then you can call [`GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) on the delegate assuming you have access to it (i.e., to get the invocation list from another class the delegate field must be public or the invocation list must be returned from a public method).

If it's an automatic event, then the field is `private` and you can only call [`GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) from within your class. You will need to do it and return the results from a `public` method to get the list from another class.

Comment: +1. I would add that there is no requirement that an object must store an event's listeners in a multicast delegate field in the first place - it can do whatever it feels like in the subscribe / unsubscribe methods. What if it chose a `Dictionary<string, Delegate>` (key being the event name) or a `List<EventHandler>` on a per-event basis?

Comment: @Ani: Definitely. But if you don't then the basic scenario (invoking all subscribers) is not as straightforward, so we 'd have to be talking about really advanced usage there.